# Push navigationcontroller animation in ios 8

Tags: ios8, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

In iOS8 I am facing one problem when I navigating(using push navigation) from one view controller to another view controller it looks like without disappear the first view controller it will show the second view controller. Example shown in below:

[image: pushing view controller]

 I am struggling with this from the last few days.How can I resolve this issue.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this : set background color of VIEW

Comment: I am already setting background color of every view controller in my application with an image using `colorWithPatternImage: ` method in AppDelegate Class.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like to bring him front:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:yourSubview]

or

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:yourSubview]

Comment: You mean, I have to add another view controller as subview or bring that view to front without pushing to another view controller

Answer (score 0):

can you please check once again background color for 
-View-Controller
-corresponding view

and it look like you have use UITABLE so check for

-table background &
-cell background

one of that is clear color.
i'm Sure there is problem with only background nothin else.

Comment: Is there any problem with background color if it is clear color